# Numerical methods for coupled stiff PDEs

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, nonlinear-equations, stiffness, coupling

I'm dealing with a set of nonlinear coupled PDEs that have the form:

\begin{align}
\frac {\partial y_1}{\partial t} &= y_2y_3 - y_1 \tag{1}\\
\frac {\partial y_2}{\partial t} &= y_1y_3 - y_2 \tag{2}\\
\frac {\partial^2 y_3}{\partial t^2} - \frac {\partial y_3}{\partial t} &=  \frac {\partial^2 y_3}{\partial z^2} + \frac {\partial y_3}{\partial z} + \frac {\partial^2 y_2}{\partial z^2} + \frac {\partial y_2}{\partial z} - \frac {\partial^2 y_2}{\partial t^2}  + \frac {\partial y_2}{\partial t} \tag{3}
\end{align}

with initial/boundary conditions:

\begin{align}
y_1(z,0) &= 10^{-5}\\
y_2(z,0) &= 10^4\\
y_3(z,0) &= 0\\
\frac {\partial y_3}{\partial t} (z,0) &= 0\\
y_1(0,t) &= 10^{-5}e^{-t}\\
y_2(0,t) &= 10^{4}e^{-t}\\
y_3(0,t) &= 0\\
\frac {\partial y_3}{\partial z} (0,t) &= 0
\end{align}

An initial approach has been to use a finite difference scheme. One being where I simply use a method of lines and treat it as a set of ODEs. But with this setup, I am having trouble formulating the above equations in such a way to actually use a stiff solver such as Gear's method since I lack an explicit expression for $$\frac {\partial y_3}{\partial t}$$

By taking the time derivative of $(2)$, I can "simplify" $(3)$ to:

$$ \frac {\partial^2 y_3}{\partial t^2} + (y_1-1) \frac {\partial y_3}{\partial t} =  \frac {\partial^2 y_3}{\partial z^2} + \frac {\partial y_3}{\partial z} + \frac {\partial^2 y_2}{\partial z^2} + \frac {\partial y_2}{\partial z} + \frac {\partial y_2}{\partial t} - y_3 \frac {\partial y_1}{\partial t}
$$

but that still doesn't help too much.

Any suggestions on methods/approaches to solve the above equations?

Comment: Don't you also need an initial condition for $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial t}$ since there is a second derivative of $y_2$ in equation 3?

Comment: @BillGreene $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial t}$ is set by equation [2] to $y_1y_3-y_2$, which is the IC.

Comment: What is the spatial domain?  What are your boundary conditions?  If they are simple enough, there may be better options.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson At this moment, I am planning to test multiple scales. Therefore $z$ may range from $10^3 - 10^{15}$, and $t$ from $10^{-3} - 10^3$

Comment: @DavidKetcheson The boundary conditions are included in the main post now.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to add one more equation defined as:

$$\frac{\partial y_3}{\partial t} = v$$

Then if you substitute equations 1 and 2 and the new equation into your modified equation 3 you get:

$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=(1-y_1)v + \frac{\partial^2 y_3}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial y_3}{\partial z} +
\frac{\partial^2 y_2}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z} + y_1y_3-y_2 -y_3(y_2y_3-y_1)
$$

Comment: Earlier, I did this with RK4 but it did not work. I then switched to [Gear's method](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/48/1/026/pdf) but was having trouble actually finding all the necessary terms since to find the updated $ \frac {\partial v}{\partial t} $ requires me finding the updated $ v $ —but this term is implicitly defined by the earlier term. Any recommendations? (Perhaps, I am missing something obvious; an example of finding the [necessary terms](http://ketch.github.io/numipedia/methods/BDF5.html) would be helpful.)

Comment: Also, besides a central difference scheme, is there a better way to handle the spatial derivatives?

Comment: Having the v term on the RHS is no different from from having the $y_i$ terms on the RHS. Obviously, equation [4] and the modified equation [3] are coupled in v but this should present no problems. As part of debugging this, I would simply try backward Euler as an integrator; it should work perfectly fine. Similarly, central difference for the spatial derivatives should also work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll try it out and get back with the results.

Comment: Also, should the backward Euler integrator be applied for all the equations or just for $\frac {\partial v}{\partial t} $?

Comment: I suggested trying backward Euler on *all* four equations because it is very simple and therefore easier to debug. When you get that working, you might want to change to a more sophisticated integrator.

Comment: Looking back, I was trying to be a bit more general with my question, in case others came across something similar, but had left out a few details. I've been trying to implement the backward Euler method, but the solutions for my particular problem are all complex-valued and I removed certain terms that were conjugated. I can split the real and imaginary parts and this then yields 8 real-valued equations that are once again nonlinear and coupled (similar to the above equations). [Here is my solution to find the necessary terms using the backward Euler integrator.](http://imgur.com/a/fT66M)

Comment: As you can see, I was able to find the terms corresponding up to the $y_3^{i+1}$ term, but I could not further isolate for $v^{i+1}$ (on a grid of 1 million+ grid points, applying a numerical solver for this part may be too computationally intensive). I'm wondering if there is perhaps another suggested, possibly better, numerical technique besides an implicit Euler method in this case? In case it's worth mentioning, I tried the implicit method on only [4] and the modified equation [3], with RK4 on the first two equations, and this did not work.